# How to detect if button was not hit / how to make something fade away if not clicked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi i am making a card inventory where i have 4 selected cards and a grid of cards to select from. when pressing a card i have a button that popps up that you can press to select the card, but my problem is that i have no clue how to make that button go away.

i want to have a select button show up when pressing a card, and pressing another will make it go away, or pressing anything else will make it go away. but i have no clue how to.

the dropdown ui template ha this built inn, when clicking the dropdown the options show up, when clicking anything else it goes away, i want that.

edit: for further clarification, i have 2 buttons, 1 makes the other one visable, the other one is going to go away when clicking anything else than the button itself. that is all i have

any idea random wonderful strangers on the internett

love

Comment: Any code, please? Anything you've tried?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary i dont have any code that conflicts with anything, which means any solution/answer/idea, might work, i have 2 empty buttons, almost. one just sets the otherone to active(true) on pressed  and the other one need to go away when clicking anything else than the button when the button is active. any idea that might do what im looking for helps :)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary i did not ask for a fix or a solution to my game specificly, i asked if there was a way to do this. and i forgot to mention i am new to this, so when you say have you tried anything? i dont know what to try, that is why i am asking in the first place. in my understanding it can be a simple function away! just that i dont know what that function would be. im simply just asking what you know, or what u would do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As I misunderstood your problem the first time, I'll write it the second time.

I think this is really simple to solve, so basically create a *huge* and transparent button which will detect all of the clicks besides from the cards and buttons.

**So my solution is:**

1. Create a button called for example "Background" and set its scale to an enormous values like 1000 to cover the whole screen all time.
2. Set all of the button's colors (Normal Color, Highlighted, Pressed, etc.) to transparent - basically **set the Alpha value to 0**
3. The button has to be above all of the other buttons in the Hierarchy of `Canvas` (or however you called it) in order to work as a background and not cover up other buttons.
4. Detect the clicks on the "Background", which will just hide the "Select" and the "Info" button.

I hope this time it will work.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i think i can clarify a little bit. the plan is to be able to select a card, so when pressing the card a select button and potentially a info button shows up under it, but if the player dont want to select it and presses another card or clicks somewhere else the select(and potentially the info button) hides again.

 so i need to detect if i press anywhere else than the button, or detect if i did not hit the button to hide the button again. 
how would i go about detecting that if you understand...

Comment: Oh, so correct me if I'm wrong - When you click a card, a select button and an info button shows under the certain card?

Comment: Yes but that i can do, but to make it dissepere when clicking anything else is my problem

Comment: By anything else you mean anything that's not a card?

Comment: anything else than the select button or info button, so pressing one card on the grid will display a info button below, then pressing another will do the same, but the past card will not have the info button show anymore, but the new one will. and also pressing for example another place on the screen will also make the info button go away.

is it possible to make the info button have a script which detects if a ray hits it or not, and if not make it setactive(false) ?

Comment: Ok, I guess I understand now, I'll edit my previous answer

Comment: https://ibb.co/DMdjyPM
https://ibb.co/qCRv9zs

here are an example of the function in a mobile game

Comment: Ok, I already edited it